# getResource() URL throwing NPE when trying to find resource

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, resources, executable-jar, imageicon

Im trying to retrieve an ImageIcon from a res folder once i have exported to a .jar hence the URL shenanigans.
This i what i have right now and does not work, this throws a NullPointer as the getResource is returning null.

```
List<Image> icons = new ArrayList<Image>();
icons.add(new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/res/itslit16x16.png")).getImage());
```

Ive also tried this;

```
icons.add(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/res/itslit16x16.png")).getImage());
```

and

```
icons.add(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("res/itslit16x16.png")).getImage());
```

Ive seen a bunch of minor variations to the aforementioned way but nothing changes. I know the Image exists as i can simply load the ImageIcon like so;

```
icons.add(new ImageIcon("res/itslit16x16.png").getImage());
```

but once ive extract the program to an executable jar it can no longer find the resources.

For reference,
this is the folder hierarchy:

[image: folder hierarchy]

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Is the *res* folder packaged within the jar?  and is it actually at the same directory level as *src*?

Comment: Not 100% sure, but id assume they ought to still be in a distinct folder from the src but on the samelevel. I just use in the Eclipse export and "Extract required libraries into generated JAR". If its not like that any idea on how to find out what the structure is changed to once in the jar?

Comment: try this: `icons.add(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("itslit16x16.png")).getImage());`  may or may not work

Comment: okay so that exactly doesn't work but really close, turns out this; `icons.add(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/itslit16x16.png")).getImage());` does work. no idea why but it does...

Comment: res is is source folder. Your images are directly under this source folder, so they're in the default package. Not in the res package. They would be in the res package if you placed them under res/res.

Comment: It's because you added the *res* folder to your `classpath` that's why in eclipse it shows the package icon inside of the folder named *res*.  Otherwise, if it were not added to your `classpath` it would just look like a regular folder icon

Comment: Instead of guessing, open your .jar file in your IDE’s file explorer.  (Every .jar file is actually a zip file.)  If `itslit16x16.png` is in the root of the .jar, then you need to start the resource name with `/`.  If you’re unclear on why the `/` is needed, read [the Class.getResource documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource-java.lang.String-).  Short version: starts with `/` → look in root of .jar file, otherwise look in same package as the class.